# Cumulocity plugin style

Tags: cumulocity

i'm trying to add a stylesheet to my plugin. I followed [this](http://www.cumulocity.com/guides/web/reference/) and added a styles folder and my css "glstyle.css" inside, then my cumulocity.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Occupation Stats",
  "description": "Parking spot occupation statistics",
  "ngModules": [
    "glsmartparking-v3.occupationstats"
  ],
  "js": [
    "index.js",
    "dateutil.js",
    "controllers/ocs-controller.js"
  ],
  "css": [
    "styles/glstyle.css"
  ]
}
```

But the css isn't loaded in the page. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That looks fine to me. Can you check that you have no error in the console? Are the js files loaded correctly? Your css file is in the styles folder within the plugin folder, right?

Comment: I indeed have a certain number of errors with lodash, I guess this is the source of my problem then?

Comment: Can you give some details on what errors you have? Also, the css file isn't loaded, or you don't see the css applied to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your plugin again with `grunt pluginRegister:<pluginName>` after changing its manifest in `cumulocity.json`?